# Basic Understanding of Elliptic curve

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

I want to know the basic understanding about Elliptic curve. Why it is need and when it is useful. I have searched much on internet but I am not a science student hence I am not able to understand the things. I want to implement Elliptic curve cryptography algorithm in my programming but I dont have basic understanding of Elliptic curve.

Comment: Please suggest me some document tutorials for that

Comment: Wouldn't trying to find a library which implements this be an immensely better way to do this? Implementing cryptographic algorithms correctly, efficiently and safely is a highly non-trivial thing, best done by people with an in-depth understanding of all the issues involved (going from the math to coding to whatnot!)

Comment: I guess I answered your question in the Cryptography Stack Exchange as well (http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/ecc-cryptography)

Comment: Why would you want to implement something that you don't yet understand? Also surely you answered your own question about uses if you want to implement one...

Comment: I have heared that it is the best and faster security implementation algorithm, hence I wanted to understand that.

Comment: Ah right, well a good place to start is the wiki pages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography

Comment: I had gone through that page, but could not find the right and understable terms

Comment: Well to understand the theory of elliptic curves you need to have a lot of prior knowledge in maths.

Comment: But I dont have :(

Comment: Depends on how well you want to understand them, and which aspects. For example, I have a PhD in somewhat related abstract algebra, so I was able to read Silverman's book. A friend with a PhD from crypto/algorithmics, but only 3 years of college algebra was struggling.

Comment: Which is the prerequisite for that ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani : Post your email id here , I will send you one elegant book . You must make sure that you must read it with dedication and interest and read every nook and corner. The book name is "Fearless Symmetry" . I send you another article by washington and also some paper presentations by Stein that may facilitate a gentle introduction .

Comment: @BhavikAmbani : Sent it, for the sake of privacy ( If you need ) you can delete your comment regarding the email Id. Thank you.

Comment: I have deleted the comment of my e-mail id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lot many articles to name.
The theory of elliptic curves, have originated a few decades earlier, but has influenced major areas, and became a central part where one can formulate a beautiful conjectures.

To add some references :

1. The Arithmetic of Elliptic curves by J.Silverman.
2. Rational Points on Elliptic Curves by J.Silverman and J.Tate.
3. If you scroll down to the bottom of [this](http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/~sdg/ecc.html) page, you exactly find a set of books, that will be very useful for a complete reference.
4. Another fantastic book which gives a very gentle introduction into the subject is Lawrence C. Washington Elliptic Curves Number Theory and Cryptography, Second Edition Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications  2008 which is available online.

And if you search in google, you can in fact find lot many paper presentations given by Prof.Silverman. Do search it.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know anything about the references at the linked site, but I wanted to point out that the two Silverman books are not at a beginner's level. They are distinctly graduate level textbooks aimed at people with a firm grasp of algebraic number theory and algebraic geometry.

Comment: @mixedmath: Rational points on elliptic curves by Silverman and Tate is readable at undergrad level. It has infact no algebraic geometry from whatever i have seen.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar : Yes, you are right. The arithmetic of elliptic curves is a bit complicated one for beginners, where as the rational points on the elliptic curves is really a good book to start. I do have sent the OP another book called " Elliptic Curves and Cryptography" by Lawrence Washington, which gives a very gentle introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the field of Cryptography lately in the recent years a lot of progress has been contributed due to progress in Elliptic Curves. The study of Elliptic Curves have been done past few decades as Iyengar pointed out, but the applications to that have been only realized lately.

Read the book http://tinyurl.com/7kjywzh (at least preview the first few pages on line to get an idea).  It all depends what you want to achieve.  If you just want to read and understand because you have a passion, then keep digging on-line.  If not, you have to choose where you are inclined to apply that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the cryptographical applications of elliptic curves, [Washington](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420071467) does a great job of introducing elliptic curves and applying them to cryptography.

Vanstone et al has a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038795273X) that doesn't spend much time talking about elliptic curves but rather talks about algorithms related to elliptic curve cryptography (ECC) and their implementation.

Finally David Jao has a [expository paper](http://djao.math.uwaterloo.ca/wiki/images/a/a1/Handbook.pdf) on ECC and Menezes an [expository paper](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/~ajmeneze/publications/pairings.pdf) on pairing-based cryptography that is often implemented in ECC for more effective security.

Answer (score 1):

For a very beginner introduction when I read this: http://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/17/elliptic-curve-cryptography-a-gentle-introduction/ I found a simple and practical explanation of the subject expecially from a developer point of view. Moreover there are basic python and javascript implementations. 
Let's say that if you intend to implement ecdsa in your software there are libraries providing secure reference implementations.